# Size of vertices of a graph in Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphs

I'm trying to produce a graph in Tikz using the *Simple* style but the vertices won't get smaller than 6pt or so and I'd like them to be much smaller. The code looks like this and if you try it out, the vertices don't actually shrink to 2pt.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\GraphInit[vstyle=Simple]
\SetGraphUnit{1.5}
\tikzset{VertexStyle/.style = {shape = circle,fill = black,minimum size = 2pt}}
\Vertex{D}
\NOEA(D){A}
\SOEA(A){B}
\SOEA(D){C}
         % \Edges{A,B,C,D,A}
\Edges(A,B,C,D,A)
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Try to also set the `inner sep` to a lower value, e.g. zero.

Comment: Worked out great, thanks! What is this parameter doing exactly, I'm not sure: is it to control the minimal size of the inside of nodes?

Comment: It's not exactly with tikz but with tkz-graph. Yes it's based on TikZ but the syntax is different but you can mix the tkz code with TikZ code. I'm not sure that everybody understand the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You also need to set the `inner sep` value to 0pt. This parameter sets the inner separation between the node content (empty box in your case) and the official node border. The `minimal size`, however, controls the minimal height and width of the node content (only).

Comment: That "node content (only)" is misleading as it could refer to "only the text" (as in the previous sentence) or "whatever is inside the node boundary".  The `minimum size` controls the minimum size _including_ the inner sep but excluding the _outer_ sep.  Try `\node[draw,inner sep=1cm,minimum size=3cm] (a) {}; \draw (a.north west) -- +(3,-3);`.

Answer (score 3):

Yes is it to control the minimal size of the inside of nodes by default I keep `inner sep =2pt`. You make a mistake with `Edges`now with the ctan version you need to use parenthesis `(A,B,C,D)`. There is a macro to draw directly a square if you want.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{tkz-graph}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \GraphInit[vstyle=Simple]
    \SetGraphUnit{1.5}
    \tikzset{VertexStyle/.style = {shape = circle,fill = black,minimum size = 2pt,inner sep=0pt}}
    \Vertex{D}
    \NOEA(D){A}
    \SOEA(A){B}
    \SOEA(D){C}
 \Edges(A,B,C,D,A)
    \end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

to get a square : i use a circle because the nodes are on a circle :)

```
\begin{tikzpicture} 
\SetGraphUnit{2} 
\Vertices{circle}{A,B,C,D}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]